# How to fine tune pre - trained transformers backbone (DiT) for object detection on custom data?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, huggingface-transformers

I want to fine tune [DiT for object detection](https://github.com/microsoft/unilm/tree/master/dit/object_detection) (text, diagrams **detection only**) etc for my own dataset. Been searching through the web for quite some time but could not find anything on fine tuning a Transformers backbone for object detection.

1. I know how to fine tune **Detectron 2** for an object detection task with the default given configuration `yaml` files using *Faster RCNN / Masked RCNN* models with *Resnet* or any other backbone CNN models but I don't know how to do it with *Transformers* models.
2. [This github issues for DETR for custom backbone](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detr/issues/428) describes how to change the backbone as the author said that **you can use ANY models from [timm library](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models)** and since there are almost 890 models present but unfortunately, not `DiT`.
3. `DiT` is also present as a [HuggingFace model](https://huggingface.co/microsoft/dit-large) and supports Feature Extraction as `BeitFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("microsoft/dit-large")` so I think it could be used as a backbone but I found nothing on this one either.

I tried changing the code on [how to train DETR on custom data](https://colab.research.google.com/github/NielsRogge/Transformers-Tutorials/blob/master/DETR/Fine_tuning_DetrForObjectDetection_on_custom_dataset_(balloon).ipynb#scrollTo=QXr3YjLlUH1T&line=2&uniqifier=1) by replacing code in Cell 8,

```
#feature_extractor = DetrFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("facebook/detr-resnet-50")

feature_extractor = BeitFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("microsoft/dit-large")
```

but while running the code for Cell 11,

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

def collate_fn(batch):
  pixel_values = [item[0] for item in batch]
  encoding = feature_extractor.pad_and_create_pixel_mask(pixel_values, return_tensors="pt")
  labels = [item[1] for item in batch]
  batch = {}
  batch['pixel_values'] = encoding['pixel_values']
  batch['pixel_mask'] = encoding['pixel_mask']
  batch['labels'] = labels
  return batch

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, collate_fn=collate_fn, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)
val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, collate_fn=collate_fn, batch_size=2)
batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))
```

it gave me error as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-446d81c845dd> in <module>
     13 train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, collate_fn=collate_fn, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)
     14 val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, collate_fn=collate_fn, batch_size=2)
---> 15 batch = next(iter(train_dataloader))

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/feature_extraction_utils.py in __getitem__(self, item)
     85         """
     86         if isinstance(item, str):
---> 87             return self.data[item]
     88         else:
     89             raise KeyError("Indexing with integers is not available when using Python based feature extractors")

KeyError: 'labels'
```

Can someone please help me with the problem t hand?

**ANY** architecture like `Faster RCNN`, `DETR` etc and **ANY** repo or platform like `Detectron 2`, `PaddleDetection`, `MMDetection`, `HuggingFace`, `EfficientDet` would do.